# How to authenticate with OWASP ZAP baseline scan

Tags: authentication, owasp, zap

I'm trying to run baseline scan with OWASP ZAP on website that uses authentication. It uses JSON-based Authentication. But when I run it I see in the results that it is not logged in.

I run it like this:

```
docker run -v C:/ZAP/:/zap/wrk owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-baseline.py -t https://myaddress.com -n somecontext.context -z "-config forcedUser.setForcedUserModeEnabled=true"
```

Here's the manual test I did.

1. Runned ZAP in GUI mode
2. Imported context
3. Turned on "Forced User Mode" by clicking the button
4. Runned automatic scan. And it worked, so i presume the context is ok

The docker mounting (-v) seems to be ok too. When I add -r report.xml I can see the report in C:/ZAP/ after zap finishes.

Comment: Do you find a way to auth with baseline scan script yet?

Comment: I've used this https://github.com/ICTU/zap-baseline as @kingthorin suggested. But had to modified it to work with my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The baseline scan is exactly as described an limited feature baseline: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ZAP-Baseline-Scan

ICTU have a third party modification of the baseline scan that supports auth: https://github.com/ICTU/zap-baseline

Comment: I've tried the one that supports auth, but it doesn't seem to work in my case. I think that the problem is that my app is async and ZAP does not wait for the inputs to appear. I've tried the one with auth on my other app that has a static logging page and it works. But i'm trying to find a way to authorize in my dynamic app.

Comment: You probably need to use the Ajax spider. I'd suggest getting it working in tue GUI then automate/script afterwards.

Comment: I've used https://github.com/ICTU/zap-baseline . But had to modified it to work with my app.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, consider contributing your mods back or writing a blog post about your setup.